# iPhone NSMutableArray Memory Leak

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, nsmutablearray

Xcode Instruments claims that the below code results in memory leak. As far as I understand, the following happens when assigning a property:
* The old value is autoreleased
* The new value is retained
* The new value is assigned obviously
With that it mind, how come I have a memory leak and how do I resolve it?

"TestProjectViewController.h":

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TestProjectViewController : UIViewController {
    NSMutableArray* array;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray* array;

@end
```

"TestProjectViewController.m":

```
#import "TestProjectViewController.h"

@implementation TestProjectViewController

@synthesize array;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {    
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        self.array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [self.array addObject:@"Hello world #1"];
        [self.array addObject:@"Hello world #2"];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
self.array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Here you retain new array object twice - when allocate it and then in setter method. One of the following should fix that:

```
self.array = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
// or
self.array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:someNumber];
```

and also do not forget to release your array in dealloc method.

Comment: do I need to release the array manually when it is a property with attribute "retain"?

Comment: Most definitely. You can also release the array by calling `self.array = nil;`

Comment: yes, property "retain" attribute defines behaviour of corresponding setter method - you increment objects retain count and so must release that object after that. If you change property value- old object will be released automatically. If you destroy your object you must release all (previously retained) its members. You can call `self.array = nil` in dealloc method instead of explicit release if you want

Answer (score 1):

Each time through the loop, you `alloc` a new array.  Each array starts with a refcount of 1, and assigning to the property increases it to 2.  You need to `release` these arrays so that the property is the only "owner" of the object.

For example, you could do this:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {    
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        self.array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [self.array addObject:@"Hello world #1"];
        [self.array addObject:@"Hello world #2"];
        [self.array release];
    }
}
```

or do this:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {    
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        self.array = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
        [self.array addObject:@"Hello world #1"];
        [self.array addObject:@"Hello world #2"];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are initializing the array inside the loop. Thats not necessary at least you assign the value of the array to another object. In that case you would also have to release it inside the loop. You are not either releasing the memory. Since you allocated memory for the array, you should release it too:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {    
  self.array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];//You just need to initialize the array just once
  for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    [self.array addObject:@"Hello world #1"];
    [self.array addObject:@"Hello world #2"];
  }
}
//Finally its necessary to release the memory when the app quits using the release method 
[self.array release]
```

Answer (score 0):

This method leaks because the `alloc/init` has an implicit retain and then the property retains it one more time. This results in each array being retained twice. You can either `autorelease` the array or `release` it at the end of the loop.

As a side note, why are you assigning a property like that in a loop? Only the last array will remain in that property. Instead, you could use a local variable and assign only the last array:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application { 
    NSMutableArray *tempArray = nil;

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        tempArray  = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
        [tempArray addObject:@"Hello world #1"];
        [tempArray addObject:@"Hello world #2"];
    }

    self.array = tempArray;
}
```